# Symfony : Sonata Media file preview

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I work on a Symfony project with sonata bundles (admin and media). I need to display a file preview - PDF file - (link to download the file or a link to display it in new tab).
I searched a lot without a good solution.
This is the field in `configureListFields`:

```
->add('cv', null, array('template' => 'admin:list_image.html.twig'))
```

This is the `twig` template code :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field %}
    <div>
        {% if object.cv != null %}
            <img src="{{ object.cv.path }}">
        {% else %}
            <span>No picture</span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: do you need to render a link or a preview (image)? How does the `cv` object look like?

Comment: no i need to render a link for pdf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by changing the template.

This is my **admin class** :

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper->add('cv', null, array(
        'template' => 'admin/list_field_cv.html.twig'
    ));
}
```

And this is my **custom template**:

```
{% extends admin.getTemplate('base_list_field') %}

{% block field %}
    {% if value %}
        {% set route_name = field_description.options.route.name %}
        {% if not field_description.options.identifier|default(false) and
        field_description.hasAssociationAdmin and
        field_description.associationadmin.hasRoute(route_name) and
        field_description.associationadmin.hasAccess(route_name, value) %}
            <div class="btn-group">

                <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block"
                   href="{{ field_description.associationadmin.generateObjectUrl(route_name, value, field_description.options.route.parameters) }}">
                    {{ value|render_relation_element(field_description) }} : to media
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block"
                   href="{{ path('sonata_media_download', {'id': (object.cv.id)}) }}">
                    {{ value|render_relation_element(field_description) }} : Télécharger
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-link btn-sm btn-block"
                   href="{% path object.cv,'reference' %}">
                    {{ value|render_relation_element(field_description) }} :  Ouvrir
                </a>

            </div>
        {% else %}
            {{ value|render_relation_element(field_description) }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, indeed it helps! Thank you for sharing your solution.